# Getting a file from aws S3 Bucket into local_ directory giving PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:

Tags: python, amazon-s3, prefect

I'm run the below task using Prefect flow task to extract a parquet file from s3bucket and save it locally but I keep getting `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:` error.

```
@task(log_prints=True, cache_key_fn=task_input_hash, cache_expiration=timedelta(days=1))
def extract_from_s3(color: str, year: int, month: int) -> Path:
    """Download trip data from S3"""
    s3_path = f'data/{color}/{color}_tripdata_{year}-{month:02}.parquet'
    s3_block = S3Bucket.load("prefect-de-zoom-s3")
    local_path = os.path.join("data", color, f"{color}_tripdata_{year}-{month:02}.parquet")
    s3_block.download_object_to_path(from_path=s3_path, to_path=local_path)
    return f'/data/{s3_path}'
```

I have run my cmd as administrator which is one of the solution I found online but the error still persist.

here is the complete error

```
 os.remove(new_filename)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\desktop\\flow\\data\\yellow\\yellow_tripdata_2021-01.parquet'
```

Comment: check if any other python program is accessing this file, remove those processes

Answer (score 0):

The double `\` looks problematic.

[Pathlib'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module can be helpful. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68234511/4590385) and other ones on that page.

The [`.as_posix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) method will "Return a string representation of the path with forward slashes (/):"

That might be helpful.